# Kayak-like filter sliders using jQuery and AJAX pagination in CakePHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, pagination

Hey everyon, I was looking at [this tutorial](http://teknoid.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/kayak-like-filter-sliders-using-jquery-and-ajax-pagination-in-cakephp/) and was wondering if anyone has an example of the completed effect.

I just want to know if it filters through the result when using the sliders but also updates the paginated numbers like on the kayak site. So lets say there is 10 pages, then you use the filter and then there are 5 pages.

If anyone has actually done or know of some place where I can see the end result as there is no demo on that site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly how it works.
Unfortunately (or fortunately) I can't really post any demos because the blog is running on the basic/free wordpress. So... no cake to demo stuff.
Maybe some day I'll get a playground site up and running... but from the looks of it, that'll be in a different life ;)

cheers.

Hope you can get this working... with a little copy/paste.